# Calculating percentage of time value is 0 vs 1

Tags: mysql

Apologies for the awful title, but I can't think of a better way of explaining this.

I have a field for each ID which can either be 0 or 1, and changes once per day based on the activity of stock in a warehouse. I.e. In stock / out of stock. This is purely used as an approximate percentage for reporting.

E.g. 10 days at 1, 90 days at 0 = 10%

What I'm doing right now is running a cron script once a day to store the current value (with timestamp) in another table, then easily working out the percentage that way.

This is working, but there must be a more efficient method? With 100,000 unique IDs for example, this equates to 26,500,000 rows per year. You can see the problem there.

I can't think of a more efficient way. Maybe there isn't one.

Answer (score 0):

You can query it dynamically using a simple select:

```
select count(if(field_name=1,1,null))/count(*)*100 as percentage_of_one from yourtable
```

field_name is the field which has to be 1 to be counted.

Comment: My apologies, I don't think my explanation was good enough...

So I have a field for each ID which can either be 0 or 1, and changes once per day based on the activity of stock in a warehouse. I.e. In stock / out of stock. This is purely used as an approximate percentage for reporting.

I am currently storing these values (with timestamp) in a separate table in order to calculate the percentage, and this is working perfectly.

However with 100,000 unique IDs for example, this equates to 26,500,000 rows per year. You can see the problem there.

I can't think of a more efficient way.

Comment: How long does your report have to go back? Do you need to store the individual statuses for some reason?

Comment: To expand on my previous question: the answer really depends on your requirements. If you need to be able to report on a specific product's availability on a given day going back for a year, then you cannot reallz design a better solution. If you need to know the percentage of in-stock products out of the total products for the last day, then you only need to store the percentage.

Comment: I only need to report the percentage for the "total" time, and as I'm storing the timestamps it's currently a simple equation. So I know that we've had that item for 200 days for example, and it has been in stock for 70% of that time.